# flask inner blueprint cannot find templates

Tags: python, flask

I'm creating a website for my CV using flask for front-end and back-end.
Each page contains a layout of an header, footer & profile info + container of the current selected content.

In order to support this structure I've created a package called **contact** that contains several blueprints (blog_blueprint, homepage_blueprint, etc...) and register them to the application on import

my project structure is:

[image]

***Clerification*** - there are no templates with the same name under different blueprints

first of all, Is that considered a good practice? if not - what are the recommandations for case like this?

second, while running the code and enter it I'm getting an error indecating that it cannot find somepage.html in my homepage_blueprint...

**homepage blueprint code:**

```
from project import db
from project.models import About, Service, Skill
from flask import render_template
from flask.blueprints import Blueprint

homepage_blueprint = Blueprint('Home Page', __name__)


@homepage_blueprint.route('/home/')
def homepage():
    return render_template(
        'homepage.html',
        about=_get_about_me(),
        services=_get_my_services(),
        desing_skills=_get_design_skills(),
        code_skills=_get_code_skills())


####################
# Helper functions #
####################
def _get_about_me():
    return About.query.one()


def _get_my_services():
    return Service.query.all()


def _get_design_skills():
    return _get_skill('Design')


def _get_code_skills():
    return _get_skill('Code')


def _get_skill(type: str):
    return db.session.query(Skill).filter_by(type=type).all()
```

Comment: please post the code of your homepage blueprint.

Comment: @gittert - I've updated my question

Comment: can you try change the blueprint line to homepage_blueprint = Blueprint('Home Page', ____name____, template_folder='templates')

Comment: After this change I'm getting 404 - my guess is that it tries to run in from a different template directory then the one that homepage_blueprint defined in....

Comment: in which py file is your homepage blueprint located?

Comment: views.py under homepage package

Comment: did you check the nr of underscores I put in my line around  " __name__ " , and bear in mind in your code in your question you are using somepage.html and not homepage.html in your py file.

Comment: Yes, I changed the number of underscores due to runtime failure. as for the name of the file - the template directory contains multiple files that are all included in the homepage.html (in my question i wrote somepage.html) - I've updated the question with image of the structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181886/discussion-between-yonatan-karp-and-gittert).

Comment: Was there any outcome of this discussion ?

Comment: No, at the end I just changed the structure of my project....